# First FETCH NEXT FROM cursor taking forever

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

Yes it needs to be a cursor

The query for the cursor is very simple - runs in a fraction of a second.

But the query returns over 300,000 rows

The first call to

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor
```

is taking forever - like 10 minutes.

What is going on? What can I do to fix this?

Some times it runs very fast.

If I have not run the TSQL for a while then some times it is very fast.

```
set nocount off 
DECLARE @randCountNew Int;

select @randCountNew = COUNT(*)
from [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
where [docSVsys].[visibility] in (0)
  and [docSVsys].[rand] = 1 ;

select @randCountNew;

 DECLARE @sIDprecict Int; 
 DECLARE @randCountThis Int;
 DECLARE @valueIDthis SmallInt;
 DECLARE @lockIDthis TinyInt;

select 'start CRREATE predict_cursor '

DECLARE predict_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT [predict].[sID], [docSVenum1pred].[randCount], [docFieldLock].[lockID], [docSVenum1].[valueID] 
FROM [docSVsys] as [predict] with (nolock) 
left join [docSVsys] as [sample] with (nolock) on [sample].[docHash] = [predict].[docHash] 
                                               and [sample].[rand] = 1
left join [docFieldLock] with (nolock) on [docFieldLock].[sID] = [predict].[sID] 
                                       and [docFieldLock].[fieldID] = 61 
                                       and [docFieldLock].[lockID] >= 3
left join [docSVenum1pred] with (nolock) on [docSVenum1pred].[sID] = [predict].[sID] 
                                         and [docSVenum1pred].[enumID] = 61
left join [docSVenum1] with (nolock) on [docSVenum1].[sID] = [sample].[sID] 
                                     and [docSVenum1].[enumID] = 61 
WHERE 
    ([predict].[RAND] is null or [predict].[RAND] = 0)
    and [predict].[textUniqueWordCount] > 10 
    and [predict].[visibility] in (0)
    and [sample].[docHash] is null 
    and [docFieldLock].[sID] is null 
    and ([docSVenum1pred].[randCount] is null or [docSVenum1pred].[randCount] <> @randCountNew)
   --and [predict].[sID] = 379045
ORDER BY [predict].[sID];

OPEN predict_cursor

Select 'FETCH NEXT FROM predict_cursor'

FETCH NEXT FROM predict_cursor INTO @sIDprecict, @randCountThis, @lockIDthis, @valueIDthis

Select 'starting cursor'

CLOSE predict_cursor;
DEALLOCATE predict_cursor;

Select 'done'
```

Every column is indexed an those joins are on PK, FK

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? Does it have a work table population step? Also look at waiting tasks and `statistics io` and `statistics time` results to see if it is busy or blocked.

Comment: @MartinSmith I will check

Comment: I assume you are closing and deallocating the cursor - you have just not shown it here?

Comment: Have you tried using a FAST_FORWARD cursor - it will be more efficient if you are just doing FETCH NEXT

Comment: @Donal I think that might be it.  In code I am closing and deallocating BUT I canceled out of the code so it never got to the close and deallocate.  How should I handle that?

Comment: @Donal The problem was that it was not getting to the close and deallocate and I was trying to open.  If you will post that as an answer I will accept.  I don't use cursor much.

Comment: @Blam ok, I see what you are saying. You executed the sql and cancelled and the cursor is still in memory. If you still have the session open you should be able to close and deallocate it. It should go out of scope when the session closes in any event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you always close and deallocate your cursors - or avoid their use if possible.

```
CLOSE predict_cursor;
DEALLOCATE predict_cursor;
```

Comment: But it solved my problem! There was a missing deallocate @c